# “An error has happened during application run.” error while installing Magento 2.1.2 with sample data

Tags: error, installation, exception, magento-community, magento-2.1.2

I've uploaded Magento 2.1.2 CE on my server and want to install it. But after one minute, I get this error:

> An error has happened during application run. See exception log for
>   details.

This is everything I have. Not log is inserted in the log files. I also tried to use the solution mentioned here but it could not sovle my problem.
Please help me ...

Comment: Anybody can't help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: try to remove caching and other folder from var folder and then try.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /var/www/html (magento root)
rm -Rf var/generation/* 
rm -rf var/di/*
bin/magento cache:clean
```

Now you will get `500 error` in the website.

```
chmod -R 777 /var/www/html (magento root)
Add sudo before command if the command does not execute
```